# Как на одностраничном сайте сделать навигацию к другим блокам по кнопке, а не по тексту?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Можно сделать ссылки якоря к другим блокам, но они работают если нажать именно на текст, который располагается в середине кнопки, нужно сделать чтоб при клике на кнопку был скролл до определённого блока.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Привели бы вы уже пример вашей вёрстки. нет сил догадываться: как у вас реализованы кнопки? Если это ссылки - тег `a`, то просто сделайте их блочными - пропишите им `display:block;` ну и задайте размеры: ширину и высоту. Если у вас кнопки реализованы иначе, то так именно? Зачем нам догадываться?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar__link {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#s1" class="navbar__link">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#s2" class="navbar__link">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#s3" class="navbar__link">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#s4" class="navbar__link">Link 4</a>
</nav>

<section id="s1">Section 1</section>
<section id="s2">Section 2</section>
<section id="s3">Section 3</section>
<section id="s4">Section 4</section>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Кажется, у  вас работает как раз только при нажатии на текст ссылок. Это натурально не то, чего хотел автор вопроса. Но я бы не торопился с ответом, пока он не покажет свои попытки сверстать самостоятельно :))

Comment: @Quazimorda - для кнопок также добавлен  ```padding```, из за этого область для клика увеличена.

Comment: Я прописал padding во всю ширину кнопки(div)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно прописать padding текста во всю ширину кнопки(div)